# How to handle a three way associations in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I am making a school application where a list of courses is needed for both the lecturers and the students, a list of lecturers for the students and a list of students for the lecturers.

So I have three models: staff, student and course.

I am new to RoR and associations don't make the most sense to me right now, but I want each staff and student to have multiple courses. So I thought `has_many` and `belongs_to`. Then I want each student to have a list of his/her lecturers, so `has_many :staff, through: :course` and the same for staff `has_many :student, through: :course`. I also want to use a paticular column for the relation, say `course_code` not an id.

staff.rb

```
    has_many :courses
    has_many :students, through: :courses
```

student.rb

```
    has_many :courses
    has_many :staff, through: :courses
```

course.rb

```
    belongs_to :staff
    belongs_to :students
```

Would this be the best way to do it if I want to be able to do `@student.course.all` and `@student.lecturer.all`?

Comment: Can a course have multiple lecturers?

Comment: Think about creating another model to serve as the bridge between the M:M relationship (something like `Enrollment`, instead of Course). A `Course` should just contain stuff about a course (stuff like `course_code`, as you stated).

Comment: Yes, and multiple students too.

Comment: @MarkMerritt I thought of that, I initially created 2 tables, Students_Courses and Staff_Courses, but I didn't know how to move forward from there.

Comment: @BeulahAkindele that seems like a reasonable solution to me. From there its just a matter of building out queries to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both students and lecturers to have courses, you'll need to use a polymorphic association.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations
Here's a guide that tells you how to implement!

EDIT: You don't need to use a polymorphic association, but it'll help DRY out your code. In addition, use concerns!

EDIT: Also, I think you need a join table. (A course can have many students, and a student can have many courses).

Answer (score 0):

So a student can follow many courses, staff can teach many courses, a courses is followed by 1 or more students, and it is teached by 1 or more staff. Reading this: you need a join table.

Still as usual, there are many different approaches to do this. Let me start with the simplest first: create two join-tables: `followed_courses` and `lectured_courses`.

```
Class FollowedCourse 
  belongs_to :student 
  belongs_to :course 

Class LecturedCourse 
  belongs_to :lecturer
  belongs_to :course 

Class Course 
  has_many :followed_courses 
  has_many :students, through: :followed_courses 
  has_many :lectured_courses 
  has_many :lecturers, through: :lectured_courses 

Class Lecturer 
  has_many :lectured_courses 
  has_many :courses, through: :lectured_courses

Class Student 
  has_many :followed_courses
  has_many :courses, through: :followed_courses
```

("Staff" is a confusing word in ruby on rails, since it has no plural: how do you indicate a group op staff versus a single staff member, that's why I propose `lecturer` here, but of course you could use teacher or anything similar).

What I could imagine is that a person, sometimes has the role of student, and sometimes the role of a teacher, so you could have a different join-table, called `ParticipatingCourses` where it belongs_to a person and a course, and has a role to indicate in which way they participate: student or lecturer. This makes things a little harder, so I think for now it would be simpler to stay with my first proposal.